# Updated solution: Add a break line to the home screen app name for Android app

Tags: android

My app name is too long… so it get truncated in the home screen of my Android phone.

I tried using \n in the app_name but it's not working…

```
<string name="app_name">AudioGasm\nRadio</string>
```

The output should be 2 lines

Audiogasm

Radio

Answer (score 1):

There is no requirement for a launcher to show your label on multiple lines. Some, such as Google's Pixel Launcher, will prevent it, to have a uniform look across apps.

So, `\n` works for adding a newline to a string resource. That newline will be honored by things like `TextView` — you can see this in your own app by using `app_name` as the text for some `TextView` in your layout.

Whether the launcher will replace that `\n` with a simple space is up to the home screen, not you. Similarly, the stock action bar will replace that `\n` with a space. However, there are some launchers that support multiple-line labels. That is up to the launcher developer.

For example, I created a scrap project with this:

```
<resources>
  <string name="app_name">My\nApp</string>
</resources>
```

In the Pixel Launcher, that shows up with one line. With Nova Launcher set to single-line mode, that shows up with one line. With Nova Launcher's single-line mode disabled, that shows up with two lines, split at the `\n`, even though it is short enough to fit on one line.

So, keep your `\n`, but just realize that it may or may not split across lines, depending on launcher.

Comment: Ok the reason I ask this is because my app_name in Homescreen gets truncated.

To avoid getting your app_name truncated in home screen. just explicitly add the "homescreen name" in the activity tag on AndroidManifest.xml

     <activity
            android:label="AudioGasm"> <—- home screen shorten title -—>

While in strings.xml, your main title will stay as is…

        <string name="app_name">AudioGasm Radio</string> <—- the exact title inside the app -—>